# Is it possible to concat two variable as method name?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to make a Typescript network library. I wonder if it is possible to create a new name by combining two const variables.

**Simple Approach**

```
const a = 'get';
const b = 'User';
const `${a}{b}` = () => console.log('getUser');
```

**Complex Version (actually what i want)**

```
const methods = [
  'get',
  'create',
  'update',
  'delete',
] as const;
const user = {} as any; // model object

const userController = createController('User', user) as &
  {
    //[key in typeof `${methods[number]}${user}`]: any;
  };
```

Expected result

```
userController.getUser
userController.createUser
userController.updateUser
userController.deleteUser
```

It should act as a type, not simply putting a value into an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable names are not dynamic this way, but property names of objects are. And you can use `{ [dynamicKeyHere]: value }` in an object literal to create a key from any string value.

So you could do something like:

```
function userController(noun: string) {
  return {
    [`get${noun}`](id: number) { return /*...*/ },
    [`create${noun}`](data: { name: string }) { return /*...*/ },
    [`update${noun}`](id: number, data: { name: string }) { return /*...*/ },
    [`delete${noun}`](id: number) { return /*...*/ },
  }
}
```

And as a starting point for the return type, you can create a [mapped type the changes the names of the name of the keys](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as):

```
type Controller<Noun extends string> = {
   [K in (typeof methods)[number] & string as `${K}${Noun}`]: () => void
}
```

Note the `` as `${K}${Noun}` ``  which is what construct the new property name.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.2&ssl=10&ssc=2&pln=8&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgUygCxAEwjAvDA2gKBhgHIBzJYgGkJOACcEBDKBKm4gVwAc1nXqixNAgA2SfvgC6MRplCQoAbnz4oATy4IYAYXBQ6IEWLoAeAHIgOYGAgAeLMBhjQ6ASzCkAfNhgBvGngA0jDuMAAU6pogAGbwSKgYAJS4YBxwAEYIdNIAZM767qQymAAGACS+gQC+FRZWVSWSAFzhidjeAG4grmj4VSrRVsBQruAwHBBZumD6hsbmltZ2Dk4uhZ5hYIstdWCJLdOzRlkLVt7+RETy0DDyR8YHegbHprveOBeXX7gl5FAVW3qjTCbV8MAYUA4dGsAHoAFQAOiRcJhMCqAi+lx+9CYLABiwakhBfnBSChsMRyNR6ICmJ+3F4eN8gLAhOJYIh5Jg8KRCJRaIxmLwJWEYiZLLZoNJkOh3MpfOpgrRKi+nNld2exj6KmusA1cyyPgmUyeBroYWIAFVJnRiIl8PqXgi-tassSYaiAO4gOgAawgQA)